# jQuery code doesn't work on Weebly - why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, weebly

newbie here. I have very limited coing skills, but OK in installing scripts to my Weebly site. Doing this for a while now and although I can not code, I learnt some things.

I would like to install a slider code I've purchased at codecanyon. Not sure if I can insert link here, but it's name is "Lush slider" you can find it at the site.

My problem is: I uploaded .js and .css files as well as images. I purchased a wysiwyg editor for the slider, and did thge slider. I have the code which I copied to the site. I can see the images before publishing but not after. it stays blank. I've found a link that Weebly might have problems with the "$" things - which I am not familiar with. Could you please help what could cause the problem?

The  code I had to insert to my footer is as follows:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
  $('.lush-slider').lush({
     baseWidth: 1455
   , baseHeight: 450
  })
</script>
```

Thanks a lot for any help!

Comment: Have a look at https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/

Comment: do you have any errors in your browser console?

Answer (score 0):

It may just be a typo in here - but you are not closing out the document ready declaration. Also check if your site has jquery by looking for either a local reference to jquery or a CDN delivered version.

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
  $('.lush-slider').lush({
     baseWidth: 1455
   , baseHeight: 450
  }); // closes the lush method
}); //closes the document.ready
</script>
```

I also found the documentation here (http://js.ofrance.fr/lush-content-slider/documentation/help.html) that may help you in setting it up and also checking that the right files are called and are called in the right order.

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked! FInally the slider is showing up after publishing the website! Huge thanks!

One more thing: it is fullwidth in laptop but have some padding right and left in mobile view. Do you have a clue where should I look for those attributes in CSS? IS there usually a separate code for mobile view or is it inside my main.css? Thanks a lot once again!

Answer (score 0):

Try using jQuery() to access it instead of $()